# Extract all maximum length values in a character vector in R

Tags: r, string, select, max

I have made a function, which basically outputs multiple length strings, i.e., for example,

```
"110110" "110"    "101"    "011"
```

Now, I assigned the output of the function in a variable a,

```
a<- c("110110", "110",   "101",    "011")
```

The class of a comes out to be character. Now, I want only those strings which have the maximum length. For example, in this example, maximum length is of "110110" . So, I want that. I tried using max command, but it returns only one maximum length string if there are multiple. For example, in strings like these,

```
a <- c("110", "101", "abc", "cab")
```

Using max command returns only, "cab". However, I want all the maximum length strings. How can I do it?

Comment: Just let me remark that `a <- c("110", "101", "abc", "cab")` is a poor example as all strings have the same length.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To measure the "length" of the string you have to use something like `nchar`. If you want all the elements which have the maximum number of characters you can filter with `nchar(a)==max(nchar(a))`. The following code should do what you are trying to do:

```
a <- c("110", "101", "abc", "cab")

a[nchar(a)==max(nchar(a))]
[1] "110" "101" "abc" "cab"
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry but, since it's the output of a function, I will execute this. So, in some places, the function returns, `""`, i.e.NULL. In those places, this code shows a warning message `In max(nchar(a)) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`. How to tackle these?

Comment: @Qin this will happen when all elements are NULL and it is just a warning, you can ignore it on those cases and the result will be, correctly, also a NULL vector.

Comment: @Qin You can also remove the zero length entries with `nzchar`. Or in the function you could include the line `if(any(nzchar(x))) x <- x[nzchar(x)]` or something along those lines.  This would get rid of those warnings when you call `max`